# Java : Error when reading input with BufferedReader

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I'm working with Java to interpret some input. And I'm using BufferedReader. My goal is to read an amount number of lines after reading a char, where -1 is the stop command. Something like this

```
2
CASE 1 - L1
CASE 1 - L2
3
CASE 2 - L1
CASE 2 - L2
CASE 2 - L3
-1
```

My goal would be have as an output just :

```
CASE 1 - L1
CASE 1 - L2
CASE 2 - L1
CASE 2 - L2
CASE 2 - L3
```

What would mean that I'm getting the lines in the right way. My code is as follows:

```
public class TESTE {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int state;

        while ((state = buffer.read()) != 45) {
            char c = (char) state;
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                int n = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    System.out.println("L:" + buffer.readLine());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason my output is:

```
L:
L:CASE 1 - L1
L: - L2
L:
L:CASE 2 - L1
L:CASE 2 - L2
L: - L3
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there an elegant way to deal with that Input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened.

1. `buffer.read()` returns `50` which is `'2'`
2. Convert it to `n`, which is `2`
3. Read two lines

Now what's next in the buffer at this point? A `\n` right after `'2'`! That's why you get your first output

```
L:
```

An Empty Line.

Well there's no point to continue. The whole process is broken.

One way to do it:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if (n == -1) break;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("L:" + in.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was stuck exactly with that! Then I found out that \n !! I just add buffer.readLine(); before the int n = Character.getNumericValue(c); and it worked fine! Your solution also gives me the same expected output! But is shorter than mine and indeed more elegant I will use that one! Thank you !!!

Comment: @Pj- if users give non-numeric input, then this code will raise exception which was handled in my answer. Shorter codes doesn't imply that they are elegant!!

Comment: @WasiAhmad thanks!! That was a very good point!! I will be more careful with that!! Thank you once more!!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `for` loop you have `buffer.readline()`. So you essentially read all your lines in one go (whereas I think you were expecting to read line-by-line).

You might want to make use of the features `readLine()` to simplify your code, eg. it returns `null` when the end of the output is reached. This would allow you to eliminate the somewhat clumsy `-1` indicating end of input.

```
String line;
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0)) {
        System.out.println("L:" + line);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that was the case then after reading the first int, the whole rest of the input would be read, and the label "L:" would appear just once, right ? Also the "3" should be in the output, what is not the case.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, you read the whole input after the first int. No, the `"L:"` appears every time because that is within the `for` loop too.

Comment: I kind get the "expected" adding buffer.readLine(); before the int n = Character.getNumericValue(c); It seems that after reading the char I still had and entire line to be read which is empty, so by doing that I was clearing that line, and the rest follows as I've said.

Comment: Also with that, It was printing also L:-1, when instead it should have terminated

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive answer can be as follows which will serve your purpose. Note that, rather than considering a single digit, its better if you consider integer because the value can be greater than 9. In that case, considering a single character wouldn't suffice!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        int value;
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(line); // if user gives non-integer values as input
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            continue; // print error message and then continue 
        }
        if (value == -1) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            line = buffer.readLine(); // keep asking for input from user
            System.out.println("L:" + line);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That indeed does exactly what I want, my original code with a little modification also works: just adding buffer.readLine(); before the int n = Character.getNumericValue(c); the it gives me the same output as yours! thank you very much!